# Disk rebuild speed low - Soalce Applinace

Tags: solace, solace-mq

After executing show disk details , I am able to see the "Disk rebuild speed low "on solace appliance 3560.

What is mean of "Disk rebuild speed low" in solace.

Answer (score 0):

The CLI command

```
disk rebuild speed <low | high >
```

changes the RAID rebuild speed of a physical appliance. The higher the rebuild speed, the faster the RAID 1 mirroring completes but more system resources are consumed for the rebuild task.

You can check disk rebuild status in the support shell with:

```
[support@solace ~]$ cat /proc/mdstat
```

and the corresponding speed limits set after changing the speeds with the above CLI command:

```
[support@solace ~]$ cat /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max
[support@solace ~]$ cat /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
```